# Perodic boundary conditions vs Dirichlet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

I have been working through several examples recently involving particles in boxes (when finding the partition function of an ideal gas for example or looking at photon gases). I have seen two approaches:

---

**Approach 1**

Take the wave function:
$$\psi=A\sin\left(k_x x\right)\sin\left(k_y y\right)\sin\left(k_z z\right)$$
And the associated boundary condition that the wavefunction must vanish at the walls. Given us:
$$\psi=A\sin\left(\frac{\pi n_x}{L_x}x\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n_y}{L_y}y\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n_z}{L_z}z\right)$$

**Approach 2**

Take the wavefunction:
$$\psi=Ae^{ik_x x}e^{ik_y y}e^{i k_z z}$$
And the associated boundary condition that the wavefunction is periodic at the walls. Given us:
$$\psi=A e^{i\frac{2\pi}{L_x} n_x x}e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{L_y} n_y y}e^{i \frac{2\pi}{L_z} n_z z}$$

---

These two approaches seem to both work in the applications I have given above (partition function of ideal gas and photon gas). Please can someone explain why this is since only the first approach is actually represents the situation at hand?

Comment: Vanishing at the walls is a special case of periodic at the walls; justcset the constant phase to zero at the end.